# Can't align div in the right place using css, html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

**Hi, I'm just having problems aligning a div (a video using iframe) on a specific place.**

See this image. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMmN7.png)

And this is what just happening

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSMS5.jpg)

I'm using bootstrap.

**Here's my html code**

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
      <!-- Header Content -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-shadow-area">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
         <!-- Video Section -->
      <div class="embed-container"><iframe class="frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5buccFsPJbg?autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&&rel=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
      <!--/END Video Section-->
      </div>
     <!-- /End Header Content --> 
 </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the css of custom class**

```
    .jumbotron {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron:before, #subscribe-bg:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  z-index:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%; 
}


.frame {
    border:5px solid #e2574c; 
}
```

**I want the video to be at the end of the background image's section like the example.**

Comment: In the "example" image the youtube frame is resting on the bottom of the screen. Is that the position you want it? Stuck to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: It's really hard to understand. Can you please help me remotely?

I will really appreciate it bro.

Here's my skype: r0ny.bd (I'll give you my teamviewer there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are setting `max-width: 50%;` on embed container, I put it on the iframe instead. Here is how I changed the code to have it aligned center bottom:

```
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 50%; 
}
```

If you set a fixed width on an absolute positioned element, in this case it's `max-width: 50%;` you can center it by setting left and right to 0 and margin: auto; for left and right sides.

Comment: use bottom: 0; instead of top:0; cuz he want it on the bottom of the page like on the example jpg file. ;)

Comment: I used 50%; because I don't want it much wider. I want it in that width.

Comment: Oh okay. Just put it on the iframe instead though because just the container is cutting it off the way you coded it. Not trying to restructure your whole layout even though it kinda could use it

Comment: @StefanBob Your code works in desktop version but not in mobile version. It's just not staying with the bottom in the mobile version

Comment: it will be easier if you use flexbox. Make a flexbox container div and apply to display: flex or inline-flex; then center it over main axis and use align-self: end; over the cross axis. Check examples here:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. ps if you cannot solve it by yourself tomorrow i will upload jsfiddle with the solution cuz now i have to leave this party.

Answer (score 0):

plz try

```
 .embed-container {
    position: relative;
   /* padding-bottom: 56.25%;*/
    height: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    max-width: 50%;
    min-height:600px;
}
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /*left: 0;
    right:0;*/
    width: 100%;
   /* height: 50%; */
}
```